# I want to transform data frame with date to time series

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I've got a `pandas.DataFrame` named "Prices" with the following data:

```
DATE            heating.oil     gasoline
2020-02-28      54.700           1.458
2020-03-02      1.521            1.523
2020-03-03      1.515            1.51
2020-03-04      1.523            1.542
...
```

Now I want to transform them to a time series.

How can I do it?

Comment: If you are using R and have loaded the package xts, `xts(prices[, -1], order.by = prices[, 1])`. See `?xts` for more info

Answer (score 0):

Use [`set_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to make the date be the data frames (or series) index, then select the columns using `Prices['...']`.

```
Prices.set_index("DATE", inplace=True)

heating_oil = Prices['heating.oil']
gasoline = Prices['gasoline']
```

**Output:**

```
DATE
2020-02-28    1.458
2020-03-02    1.523
2020-03-03    1.510
2020-03-04    1.542
Name: gasoline, dtype: float64
```